# How to run 'alter user' command from C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a oracle database and whenever a user account gets locked I run the command,

```
ALTER USER xxxxx ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```

Is there a way to execute this from an C# application?

Comment: Sure. What did you try? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is same as other databases. You will create an `IDbCommand` on an open database connection, assign it the query to be fired and execute it.

```
static void Main()
{
    string constr = //Connection string         
    DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Oracle.DataAccess.Client");     

    try
    {
      using(DbConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection())
      {
          conn.ConnectionString = constr;
          conn.Open(); 
          using(DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
          {
             cmd.CommandText = "ALTER USER xxxxx ACCOUNT UNLOCK;"; 
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
      Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

Comment: DbConnection should be wrapped in a `using` block, as it implements `IDisposable`.