# Enter Alter User Statement into Oracle using C#

Tags: c#, oracle

I am making a tool to reset/unlock oracle users in c#, I use the following statement via sqlplus to unlock users "ALTER USER myUserName ACCOUNT UNLOCK;" However, every time I execute the statement via my c# code bellow I get this error! I am reaching out for help after hours of trial and error! Any help would be great!

Also, if anyone can advice how to get the response from Oracle after submission of the statement?

Thank you all in advance!

```
           public ActionResult SubmitRequest()
    {
            String connectionString ="Data Source = (DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myHost)(PORT=1234)) (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=mySID)));"+
            "User Id="+Username+";"+
            "password="+password+ ";";

            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "ALTER USER myUserName ACCOUNT UNLOCK;"
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            con.Close();
            return View();
    }
```

Error:

```
           Server Error in '/' Application.
           Invalid operation. The connection is closed.
           Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

           Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid operation. The connection is closed.
           Source Error:
           Line 134:                    cmd.CommandText = CommandUnlock;
           Line 135:                    con.Open();
           Line 136:                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and also I get the same error when I use - "cmd.ExecuteScalar();"

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link:

[How to run 'alter user' command from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32269377/how-to-run-alter-user-command-from-c-sharp)

Otherwise, You can write a procedure like bellow and execute it from C#.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UNLOCK_USER(P_USER IN VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER USER ' || P_USER || ' ACCOUNT UNLOCK';
END UNLOCK_USER;
```

Comment: Thanks Mahdi for your help here! :)

Comment: I used that link to build my code, I honestly doubt that it ever worked! After some research, my code looks how I posted it. but Initially I started with what I grabbed from that link. As for your past post, I need to unlock a user, not to find the state of the user. 

Excuse my lack of knowledge here, I somewhat of a nooob trying to learn. 

How do I create a procedure? where would I enter:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UNLOCK_USER(P_USER IN VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER USER ' || P_USER || ' ACCOUNT UNLOCK';
END UNLOCK_USER;?

Comment: You can use these application pl/sql developer, oracle sql developer, SQLPlus to create your procedure. Or even you can use your C# IDE to create it. With these apps, You should login in your schema, then open new SQL Window and then create your procedure. Note: Your oracle user must have grant to alter user xx.

Comment: @MahdiGhasri bro you may go on with editing your unique answer(double answer of you appear ;) ).

Answer (score 0):

You never associate the command with the connection. Youshould also use a `using` block to make sure the command and connection are disposed properly::

```
using(OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString)
using(OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("ALTER USER myUserName ACCOUNT UNLOCK;", con)
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: no errors! Thank you!! when the statement is is sent via directly from SQLPlus, there is a response

Comment: There is a response indicating if the user was altered, or if the username was not found, or if the password is being reused, so on. w

Comment: Would you know if there is a way to get the response from C#?